# trigger Event from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, sharepoint

I have two Webparts on a sharepoint site ... thats basicly like haveing two iframes . What I want to do is if there is a change at webpartA , I want to update WebpartB ... what I did so far is at WebpartA I try to trigger a custom event:

```
$("#datain").change(function () {
    parent.$("document").trigger("datachange" , [$("#datain").val()]);
})
```

At Webpart B I added a Eventlistener :

```
parent.$("document").on('datachange',function (event, data) {
    $("#dataout").html(data);
});
```

When I change something at WebpartA , the event is triggered , but it never reaches the event listener at WebpartB. 
Is there something wrong with my code or is it just impossible to communicate between the two iframes with custom Events ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can use "window.postmessage" to communicate between the iframes, 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Answer (score 0):

fixxed the problem by changeing "document" to "body"
so Webpart A is :

```
$("#datain").change(function () {
    parent.$("body").trigger("datachange", [$("#datain").val()]);
})
```

and Webpart B is :

```
parent.$("body").on('datachange',function (event, data) {
    $("#dataout").html(data);
});
```